# H2 and P on same line (HTML, CSS, PHP)

Tags: html, css

Hi i would like to have my h2 heading and p on the same line with 2 empty spaces between them. I have tried almost all solutions but i dont know what im doing wrong. Here is my CSS and HTML:

```css
h3 {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 20px;
  display: inline;
  color: #00cccc;
}
publish_date {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ff0033
}
```

```html
<publish_date>Lorem ipsum</publish_date>
<h3>Sit amet</h3>
```

Comment: `<publish-date>` is not a valid `HTML` tag.

Comment: why php is tagged?

Comment: Where is you `p` tag? All is see is `h3` and `publish_date`..

Comment: Make them `inline` or `inline-block`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman it doesn't have to be a valid tag for styles to work.

Comment: @mistermartin Yes, But there must be some strong reason while using some invalid `HTML` tag. I'm curious to know what is that in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this out!

**CSS**:

```
p, h3{
    display: inline-block; /* display on the same line */
}
h3{
    position: relative;
    left: 20px; /* this will not work without setting position property */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #00cccc;
    float: right;
}

p{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ff0033
    text-align: left;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<p><?php echo $the_publish_date ?></p><h3><?php echo $article_title1 ?></h3>
```

Just for your information, as **Muhammad Usman** stated, "`<publish-date>` is not a valid `HTML` tag", and whilst you are able to do this, there is no real point to it. You might as well just stick to the native `<p>` or `<span>` tags.

Hope it helps!

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n3kmd9ye/**

Answer (score 0):

Add to `h3   float:left; margin-right:10px;`
float:left will put the next to each other and with the margin-right you can control the distance between them.

```css
h3 {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 20px;
  display: inline;
  color: #00cccc;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}
publish_date {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ff0033
}
```

```html
<publish_date>Lorem ipsum</publish_date>
<h3>Sit amet</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit outdated here but this is the way how I solved it.

Put a wrapper around the two elements like this:

```
<div class="publish-wrapper">
    <publish_date>Lorem ipsum</publish_date>
    <h3>Sit amet</h3>
</div>
```

And then use a flexbox.

```
.publish-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```